# How can I enable Web Live Preview in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: webforms, visual-studio-2022

My company DOES have an ASP.NET WebForms / framework application, and we DO have Visual Studio 2022 installed.

But the "Design" window looks just the way it did ten years ago.

What is required to enable Web Live Preview?

Or was the feature pulled from the product "at the last minute"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the settings for this option are here:

Tools->options->Web Forms designer

[image]

So, a given web page in design mode that looks like this:

[image]

Now, with live preview looks like this:

[image]

So, note how even the menu bar shows, and the css styles also show
(really nice!!).

And you can even turn on live preview of data.

So, you now see this:

[image]

There are a few more things (like bread crumbs for each element - can't seem to find that option.

So, why is this NOT going to knock your socks off?

Why is this feature not going to start a revolution as big as when drag + drop for VB arrived the desktop?

Answer:

They decided this feature was for a preview feature, AND NOT A DESIGN feature!!!

I simply cannot stress as a result HOW this feature misses the mark here.

Remember, if you REALLY but really need a good preview of the page, with final rendering? Then you run the page!!!!

We of the web form community love the web forms designer since it allows the drag and drop of components onto a design surface. Since the new designer does not facilitate drag and drop onto the designer, then this becomes a preview tool AND NOT A DESIGN tool.

As a result, what amounts to one of the best new features of vs2022?

What amounts to one of the most fantastic upgrades to web forms?

Well, it is much a hug without the kiss. Removing the ability to visual drag + drop onto the design surface?

Well, then 99 out of 100 users will try the new live preview. And we all think wow, is that cool, is that great, is that nice!!!

However, the VERY instant the SAME group of users finds out that you can't drag + drop into that new live design preview? Then we all just turn the feature off, go back to the older designer. While the older designer doesn’t render much of a decent looking page?

We don’t' care - what we ALWAYS cared about was the drag + drop design surface.

And with HTML5 standards finally becoming real standards that are not changing so much?

Then EVERY and I repeat EVERY new IDE and design suites are ALL MOVING back towards visual designers.

This new feature could have set the stage for introducing  whole new group of web developers into the world of drag and drop (something we enjoyed on the desktop for years). However, without support for drag + drop into this new super duper great and fantastic preview option?

Then this feature becomes a preview tool, and not a developer and designer tool.

***And we all use webforms for the designer side ability, and the preview fact is nice, but a secondary goal.***

But, to make a long post short?

Yes, the feature exists, and is one of the better new features in vs2022, and this new feature is for webforms only.